# Conditional logic for woocommerce variable product

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a product with 2 combinations:

1. OS = Mac -> Dropdown should have 2 options "Macbook Air", "Macbook Pro".
2. OS = Windows -> Dropdown should have these 2 instead "Surface Book", "Lenovo ThinkBook".

I have a label variation where u can select a operating system "Mac" or "Windows".
Depending on what the client selects he should be shown the options related to that.

Right now i currently have a dropdown with all 4 models "Air, Pro, Surface, Thinkbook"..

So if a client selects "Mac" in first variation, he should only be able to select "Macbook Air", and "Macbook Pro" in next variation.

Is this possible through functions.php without using any other wordpress plugin?

Comment: Yes this is possible… But we expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please kindly note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea how to do this, thats why i hoped someone knew.

Comment: Some javascript (jQuery) is required with some template customizations: This will allow you to have a kind of multistep just as you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't accomplish it with functions.php. PHP is a server-side language meaning it can only handle logic before page load. You need a client-side language such as Javascript to handle this without reloading the page, which is fine as it plays nicely with Wordpress. Here's a minimum example demonstration of how to do it in Vue, a common JS framework and the one I use most often with Wordpress. You can read the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) and get a quick understanding of how this works.

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <select name="os" id="os" @change="setOs">
        <option value="">Select OS</option>
        <option value="mac">Mac</option>
        <option value="windows">Windows</option>
    </select>
    <select name="computer" id="computer" @change="setComputer" v-if="os">
        <option value="">Select Computer</option>
        <option value="air" v-if="os === 'mac'">Macbook Air</option>  
        <option value="pro" v-if="os === 'mac'">Macbook Pro</option>
        <option value="surface" v-if="os === 'windows'">Surface Book</option>
        <option value="thinkbook" v-if="os === 'windows'">Lenovo Thinkbook</option>
    </select>
    <p v-if="computer">Selected computer: {{computer}}</p>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#container",
  data: {
    os: null,
    computer: null
  }, 
  methods: {
    setOs: function(e){
      this.os = e.target.value;
    }, 
    setComputer: function(e){
      this.computer = e.target.value;
    }
  }
})
```

You can view [this pen](https://codepen.io/kslaton/pen/poNPOmo) to see it in action.

Comment: For info, WooCommerce / WordPress doesn't use for instance Vue.js library. They use JQuery which is included by default.

Comment: Correct, but you can add it yourself. Get it off the CDN and enqueue it just like any other script. You can also accomplish the same thing I just did using jQuery, it just looks a little different.